# How to connect to Amazon RDS using go-sql-driver

Tags: mysql, go, amazon-rds

I can connect to the RDS instance using `mysql -h ...` command so I know it's not a security group problem.

I've tried to use:

```
sql.Open("mysql", "id:password@tcp(your-amazonaws-uri.com:3306)/dbname")
```

in the readme file of go-sql-driver(https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql), but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using my username under the RDS instance instead of id here though.

Edit:
The error returned is: `panic runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer deference [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x5b551e]
goroutine 16 [running]
runtime.panic(0x7d4fc0, 0xa6ca73)...database/sql.(*Rows).Next...`

It works fine with my local DB.

Comment: It should return an error, please post it.

Comment: Is the problem solved? I need help on it.

Answer (score 5):

The connection string for sql.Open() is in DSN format.

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "<username>:<password>@tcp(<AWSConnectionEndpoint >:<port>)/<dbname>")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Print(err.Error())
}

defer db.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the actual error isn't related to an import issue (as in [`issues 266`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/266#issuecomment-51594503))

Check (to be sure you are using the latest versions, as in [this issue](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/150#issuecomment-27617548)):

- your Go-MySQL-Driver version (or git SHA)
- your Go version (run `go version` in your console)

If the error isn't directly in the Open step, but when accessing the Rows, [check this comment out](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/36#issuecomment-14482643):

> Use either a `for` loop (`for rows.Next() { ... }`) or something like this:

```
if rows.Next() {
     // whatever
} else {
     // catch error with rows.Err()
}
rows.Close() // <- don't forget this if you are not iterating over ALL results
```

Comment: I went through everything you mentioned. What I'm doing works perfectly fine with my local MySQL instance. The only difference between the two DB instances (local vs RDS) is the MySQL version. Do you thinks that's a possible cause?

Comment: @UserNotDefined yes, it could be a cause for miscommunication.